# decoding android h264 encoded stream on windows using media foundation

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to decode h264 encoded camera frames streamed from an android device on a windows pc. 
I am using the MediaFoundation H264 decoder to decode every frame sent from the android device. However I keep on getting the error 'more input samples are required to process output error'.

The following is the requirement of the MF H264 Decoder:

`Media samples contain H.264 bitstream data with start codes and has interleaved SPS/PPS. Each sample contains one complete picture, either one field or one frame.`

I was wondering if this is compatible with what i am sending from the android device.

I am using the code below to send frames to the windows device:

```
    private static class AvcEncoder {

        private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
        final static int FRAME_RATE = 15;
        final static int MOTION_RANK = 2;

        public AvcEncoder(int width, int height) { 

            mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
            MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, (int)(width*height*FRAME_RATE*MOTION_RANK*0.07));
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
            mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            mediaCodec.start();
        }

        public void close() {
            try {
                mediaCodec.stop();
                mediaCodec.release();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e){ 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //frames are sent here
        public void offerEncoder(byte[] input) {
            try {
                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
                int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                    inputBuffer.clear();
                    inputBuffer.put(input);
                    mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
                }

                MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,0);
                while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
                    byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                    outputBuffer.get(outData);
// write frame length
                    byte frameLength[] = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(outData.length).array();
                    outputStream.write(frameLength, 0, 4);
// write the actual frame
                    outputStream.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                    Log.i("AvcEncoder", outData.length + " bytes written");
                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                    outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

If required I can also post the Windows code.

Also, When i save the streamed data to a file, i am able to play it in VLC, so VLC is able to understand and decode it quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the fix was very simple. I don't know why but Media Foundation requires you to set either the duration or time-stamp of each sample fed to the decoder. The output however doesn't seem to be effected in any way by these two parameters.

Edit:
Note that the `InputProcess` method of the `IMFTransform` should return `MF_E_NO_SAMPLE_DURATION` or `MF_E_NO_SAMPLE_TIMESTAMP` if sample duration or timestamp is not set in the `IMFSample` object passed to the `InputProcess` method. However, in my case it didn't return any such values.